# Can This be a Valid Catholic Imprimatur?

Tags: catholicism, canon-law, authorship, imprimatur

Recently, I came across a book published in 2012 which indicates an "Imprimatur" (i.e., permission to print) from Reverend Joseph R. Binzer, Auxiliary Archbishop, Archdiocese of Cincinnati. It contains, however, no Nihil Obstat (which indicates that the book is not objectionable on doctrinal or moral grounds).

I don't recall having ever seen a book published with an Imprimatur but no Nihil Obstat.

An example from another of his book:
[image: Example of imprimatur page]

---

QUESTION: Should I have reason to suspect that the Imprimatur is not valid? I ask this, because:

1. How can an archdiocese mandate "let it be printed" without having first assigned it to a qualified censor to determine if there is anything contained therein objectionable to the Catholic Faith?
2. Can an auxiliary bishop grant an Imprimatur? I thought that the granting of a valid Imprimatur comes is the prerogative of the local ordinary alone---which in this case would be the archbishop of Cincinnati---provided of course, that either the real author resides in Cincinnati or the book was published in Cincinnati? Incidentally, the book indicates a publisher based in Erlanger, KY, which is within the diocese of Covington, KY---and not Cincinnati.

QUESTION 2: The author indicated on the book is a young (< 50 years old) Australian who operates several companies and publishes many, many books (with his name on it)---some of which have been marketed to both Catholics and Protestants under "different" publishing companies. *If* a ghostwriter is involved, how does Canon Law account for that? I interpret the author as being the one who actually writes the book, not necessarily the one who's name appears on the book.

Comment: In the absence of a picture of the page where the imprimatur appears, I think it would be helpful if you could provide the title, author, and/or ISBN of the book, so that someone else can procure that image.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple The book is "The Four Signs of a Dynamic Catholic". Indicated author: Matthew Kelly.  Amazon link:  https://www.amazon.com/Four-Signs-Dynamic-Catholic/dp/1937509664 --- I have noticed that when I "look inside", though the date on Amazon is 2012--- it now contains no Imprimatur and indicates a publisher address of Hebron, KY. --- Hopefully, I can upload a picture of the page your equest from my book, shortly.

Comment: At any rate, I found an example from another of Matthew Kelly's book [here](https://fadakay.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Matthew-Kelly-Rediscover-Catholicism-Beacon-Publishing-2002.pdf).  PDF page 3 contains something that matches your description.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I am glad you were able to post this; for some reason, my AdobeScan is not forwarding my scan to me---have yet to figure out what the problem is. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure.  I added the picture to the Q, although it may not be precisely the one you see, since it does say the book is free from "doctrinal or moral error".

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Many thanks. That is most helpful.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Indeed, this is most interesting; --- That I recall, I have never seen an Imprimatur granted by a Vicar General.

Comment: Are we all just going to ignore the typo ("Cannon Law") in the grant?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good eyes! In fact, after reading your comment, I checked "The Four Signs of a Dynamic Catholic" book mentioned in an earlier comment and the same error appears.

Answer (score 3):

1. Canon Law does not require the appointment of a Censor Liborum according to the 1983 code. See [When does a Catholic book need an imprimatur](https://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2019/01/03/when-does-a-catholic-book-need-an-imprimatur/) for additional details. In that case, a book could have an *imprimatur* without a *Nihil Obstat*
2. Usually it is the Ordinary -- the Bishop or Archbishop that heads a diocese:

[Can. 824 §1](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib3-cann822-833_en.html) Unless it is established otherwise, the local ordinary whose permission or approval to publish books must be sought according to the canons of this title is the proper local ordinary of the author or the ordinary of the place where the books are published.

In this specific case, the auxiliary bishop was also vicar general (incidentally, Canon Law requires an auxiliary bishop to be vicar general). The vicar general acts on the authority of the Ordinary in a unique way in Canon Law -- the authority of the vicar general is not considered delegated from the bishop and hence you also cannot appeal from the vicar general to the ordinary. Thus, the vicar general in this case likely approved the book by acting in that capacity.

Canon Law at least for imprimaturs does not take account of "ghost writers" -- it is the work itself not the author which is scrutinized for defects in faith and moral.

Comment: Thank you for posting this informative answer.  One reason I inquired about a ghostwriter is because if say, I wrote a book and wanted to submit a book I wrote for an Imprimatur---I only have two choices: (1) The (arch)diocese where I, the author, live; or (2) The (arch)diocese where the book is to be published. Since, the aforementioned book seems to have been published in Erlanger, KY --- it would seem that the author must then have lived within the archdiocese of Cincinnati---which could have been possible, I suppose; but if a ghostwriter is involved---I was wondering if anything changes.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this particular book could have been approved by the Archdiocese of Cincinnati at that time -- I don't see any particular rule which would allow that. Again, I don't see how a ghost writer changes anything. The local ordinary of the author meaning the person who wrote the book not just whose name appears on it.

Comment: I just came across this: According to page 1 (first paragraph) of https://www.usccb.org/about/doctrine/publications/upload/permission-to-publish.pdf --- it would seem that it is the archbishop (or bishop) who can grant ecclesiastical approval for publishing a book---not an auxiliary bishop or  vicar general. The latter statement is but my interpretation.

Comment: "Local ordinaries in the Latin Catholic Church are defined in law as diocesan
bishops, those who are placed over a particular church or equivalent community (e.g., diocesan administrators), vicars general, and episcopal vicars acting
within the scope of their designated responsibilities.42 "

Comment: As there can be only one local ordinary in a diocese, am I correct in assuming that, say, a vicar general can be considered  to be a (the) local ordinary in the event that the Pope appointed him as a diocesan administrator because the bishop has either retired, resigned, or been removed?

Comment: Also, regarding my concern over ghostwriters: Please see the bottom of page 7 in the link   I previously sent:   6. Who may grant the authorization for written works?
Another essential determination a diocesan or eparchial official must make
upon receiving a request to approve a written work is whether the diocese or
eparchy possesses the competence needed to review the text. In the Latin
Catholic Church, the task of granting the required permission or approval
belongs to 1. The proper local ordinary of the author 2. The ordinary of the place where the book is to be published.

Comment: So, if the indicated author is not really the author--- 2., (I interpret) must then be the local ordinary of the ghostwriter.  That's how I read it.

Comment: No. It lists distinct possibilities. A diocese administrator would be the ordinary regardless of whether he had previously been the vicar general. The ordinary means the one possessing *ordinary* as opposed to *delegated* jurisdiction. A vicar general as stated above uniquely doesn't possess delegated jurisdiction from the bishop and yet is subordinate to him.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? The ordinary of the person who wrote the text has competency or the ordinary where it is published.

Comment: But doesn't "ghostwriter" mean that the "author's" name printed on the book cover is *not*  the person who actually wrote the book? Hence, if a ghostwriter wrote a book, and the book is submitted for ecclesiastical approval to the diocese of the indicated author, the Imprimatur, if granted, could not be valid since the actual author and his residence is unknown. It's the residence of the author that matters when a book is submitted for ecclesiastical approval outside of the diocese where it is actually published.

Comment: It does. I said the person who wrote the book would be the author for the purpose of canon law. In other words, if you put someone else's name on it, that doesn't canonically change who may approve it. Furthermore, if you lie or deceive the bishop by claiming you wrote something that someone else actually did (i.e. you hire a ghostwriter), not only would you render the imprimatur invalid if that person lives in a different domicile but you would sin.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.